# Scrapy SgmlLinkExtractor and span attribute

Tags: python, scrapy

I need to match  attribute against some strings.
I tried to add the span attribute to sgmllinkextractor but it seems to ignore it since it has no link in it.

is there an option to use a callback function that will be called when no link could be extract via linkExtractor?

I want to match the page against some string if and only if there was no match with linkExtractor.

Thanks

Comment: try subclassing BaseSpider instead of using CrawlSpider

Comment: To mark a question as solved - accept an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try subclassing [BaseSpider](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#basespider) instead of using CrawlSpider.